# google search api issue

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-search-api

I implemented google search API for shopping into my project, but as for now the request returns json obect with response code 200 (OK) and returns no items(there is even no "items" field). When i type my request in browser, but change GAN for public, it returns many items. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved.
I had to check the affilates in my google account.